# Issue Recognizing FB Comments on Home Page

Tags: php, facebook

I'm new to programming and I could use your help.

I've been having trouble changing

```
<?php comments_number(__('No Comments', 'engine'), __('1 Comment', 'engine'), __('% Comments', 'engine')); ?>
```

to a line that recognizes the total number of comments made by fb users, and inputs them correctly as meta-comments on the main page.

I've been able to do this on posts themselves in the single.php using

```
<span class="meta-comments"><fb:comments-count href="<?php echo get_permalink($post->ID); ?>"></fb:comments-count> Comments</span>
```

But when I try to use this on the index.php is does not work.

My site is www.theclassicgamer.com

I've been stumbling on this for quite a few hours, and I feel it's time to request help.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you give more detail on what output you get when you try it?

Comment: Sure, when inputting the same line into the index.php as I have into single.php It results in showing "Comments" but does not recognize the count. I have input that code into the index.php for your view.

Comment: Can you show us the `comments_number()` function?  I don't see anywhere that the first line of code is working.  What are you using to connect to the facebook API in PHP/Wordpress?

Comment: This is my comments.php

<div id="fb-root"></div>  
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1"></script>  
<fb:comments href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" width="620"></fb:comments> 

I am not sure where the comments_number() function would be located, but I would assume it should be in there.

Comment: <h3 id="comments"><?php printf( _n( 'One Response to %2$s', '%1$s Responses to %2$s', get_comments_number() ),
         number_format_i18n( get_comments_number() ), '&#8220;' . get_the_title() . '&#8221;' ); ?></h3>

Comment: BTW you should edit the extra information requested into your original question so that it makes sense without having to read through the comments (which don't allow such rich formatting).